# G, H, ', 0,1 Keys stopped working

Tags: keyboard

I have an  Dell Inspiron N7010. The <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>'</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd> keys no longer work.

I plugged in a external keyboard and it works.
I have tried removing the battery and holding the power button for a few seconds.
I tried cleaning and resetting the ribbon cable.
I tried cleaning the keyboard with air.
I tried uninstalling the keyboard from the device manager.
I tried disabling the Bluetooth.

Nothing has worked so far. Any suggestions? Should I order a new keyboard?

Comment: I don't have experience with that exact model, but on one Dell laptop I once owned the keys could be popped off by levering underneath the edge (with a penknife, for example). If this is possible, it gives better access to clean the contacts/mechanism and may help you restore the key function.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely get a new keyboard. You can most likely find one for a decent price on ebay for your **EXACT** model. Make sure it comes with the appropriate connector and buy new if possible. Installation is pretty easy and there are plenty of guides out there, but it is a delicate process. Most laptop keyboards are ribbon connectors which can break easily.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're experiencing is usually caused by failure of a particular section of the [keyboard matrix circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_matrix_circuit).

You'll need to replace the keyboard to fix this issue. The procedure is documented in page 37 of the [service manual to your laptop](ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_inspiron_laptop/inspiron-17-n7010_service%20manual_en-us.pdf). While keyboard replacement doesn't appear to be a particularly complex procedure, it does require careful handling of the parts involved.